# Check username and password with every instance made of a class

Tags: java, class, authentication

I want to write a `Person` class that has their details, including a username and password.

What I want then to do is create a login where the user types in their username and password and then it gets checked for every instance that has been created of that class

```
if (p1.getUser == userInput && p1.getPass == passInput)
{
    Login();
}
else
.... Check the next instance until you've checked every instance.
```

Can anyone think of a good way to pull that off?

Comment: You'd need to keep a list of instances somewhere, perhaps as a static collection. Also, compare strings with `.equals`, not `==`.

Comment: Can you please demonstrate that you've done more work on your project than 5 lines of pseudo code?

Comment: I've only been building interfaces so far. im trying to design the classes that hold information and the functionality now

Comment: if this is homework, it should be marked as such

Comment: maybe if i have a second class storageSystem or something like that and everytime i create an instance i save it in an arrayList in that class. how does that sound?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would (basically like every web site on the planet) store the users in a database and use a query to find them:

```
select * from my_user where username = ? and password = ?
```

Note: Normally, the password is saved as the hash rather than the plain text

However, if you really want a code-only solution, do this:

```
List<Person> people = new ArrayList<Person>();
// populate people

public Person login(String username, String password) {
    for (Person person : people) {
       if (person.getUser().equalsIgnoreCase(username) &&
           person.getPass().equals(password))
           return person;
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot thats similar to with what i was thinking. Dont really know why i got a -2 for asking it but anyway. Sorry i cant +1 but my reputation is still to low

Comment: @user967797 Your rep is big enough now to +1 my answer :)